# Hover Zoom Effect While Using Object-Fit: Cover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My goal is to have a zoom in effect when a user hovers over an image on my page. I have found code that has this effect;

```
.transition {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.6); 
    -moz-transform: scale(1.6);
    -o-transform: scale(1.6);
    transform: scale(1.6);
}
#content {
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}
```

Adding the transition to the content when the user hovers over the image.

The problem that I am having is using this technique combined with object-fit: cover. I want the image to fit into a fixed size box (Height: 250px; Width: 25%), while maintaining its aspect ratio (which is accomplished using object-fit: cover).

But, when a user hovers over an image with object-fit: cover, it reverts back to its old aspect ratio, does the zoom, and then goes back to the proper aspect ratio. This leads to some very odd visuals, which can be seen in the following fiddle;

http://jsfiddle.net/y4yAP/982/

Removing the object-fit: cover on #content will fix the problem with the zoom, but distort the aspect ratio.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: This is happening to me also with object-fit, but only on Firefox. On Chrome works flawlessly. IE and Edge don't even display the page...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`object-fit:cover` isn't widely supported and I'm not very familiar with it, I don't know if you are required to use it but I tried something I am more familiar with.

If all the images are 'landscape' then you can use `width: 100%` and `height: auto` and the CSS will maintain the aspect ratio for you. To position the images centered in the container I applied `position: relative` to the container and `position: absolute` to `#content`. See: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/

For the zoom you can just use `#content:hover { ... }` in your CSS (unless you need jQuery for other purposes).

HTML:

```
<div id="imageDiv">
    <img id="content" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/78/Small_scream.png" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content:hover {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) scale(1.6); 
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) scale(1.6);
    -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) scale(1.6);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) scale(1.6);
}

#content {
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

#content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%); 
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

#imageDiv { 
    position: relative;
    height: 250px;
    width: 450px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

FIDDLE (sans js): http://jsfiddle.net/pqs4vef7/2/

Comment: Oh man, it looks like this may be exactly what I need. The Div is a fixed height/width, which the image crops to fit. The image maintains is aspect ratio. The zooming works perfectly, with nice smooth transition. I am going to try to implement this into my site in a couple hours, and if successful throw you ALL my upvotes. Thanks for your help, I will report back.

Answer (score 3):

Please check all you need to do is the the width to "max-width", and remove the object-fit:

www.jsfiddle.net/y4yAP/985/

Comment: This solution does not maintain the aspect ratio. As I mentioned in my above post, removing object-fit will allow the zoom to function properly, but distorts the aspect ratio of the images. In other words, I need the image to look how it does in my fiddle, but I need the zoom to function like it does in your fiddle. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Could you show me the full html, css? or the page where you try to do it

Comment: I cannot show the full HTML or CSS, but the fiddles perfectly illustrate the problem that I am having. With object-fit: cover the zoom does not work properly, but the aspect ratio is perfect... without object-fit:cover the zoom works properly, but the aspect ratio is off.

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/y4yAP/986/ If you want to keep the aspect ratio use: http://jsfiddle.net/y4yAP/987/

Comment: Is It what you wanted?

Comment: Thank you for the response, Valery. So close! Unfortunately I suppose I forgot to mention one requirement, that the width is fixed (to 25% of the screen). So while the first one works perfectly, the aspect ratio is still not right, and the second one changes the size of the image. \

Comment: That's why i asked to see all of the images.. so I can control the output

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I am not able to make the page public. It is not a personal page, it is work related. I have tried my best to recreate the situation, but the image width was an oversight.